# filling an ImageSource with a selector

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to fill up an image from a selector based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/photo-picker

the selector works fine and the stream fills up. however i do not get the picture on my screen.

```
    public Command SelectPictureCommand { get; }

    public ImageSource ItemPic { get; set; }

        SelectPictureCommand = new Command(execute: async () =>
        {
            if (IsBusy)
            {
                return;
            }

            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    ItemPic = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        });
```

xaml

```
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Button Text="Select Picture" Command="{Binding SelectPictureCommand}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding ItemPic}" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should  implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your ViewModel or Model:

> ViewModels generally implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
>   which means that the class fires a PropertyChanged event whenever one
>   of its properties changes. The data binding mechanism in Xamarin.Forms
>   attaches a handler to this PropertyChanged event so it can be notified
>   when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new
>   value.

```
public class myViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Command SelectPictureCommand { get; }

    public ImageSource itemPic { get; set; }


    public ImageSource ItemPic
    {
        set
        {
            if (itemPic != value)
            {
                itemPic = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemPic"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return itemPic;
        }
    }

    public myViewModel() {

        SelectPictureCommand = new Command(execute: async () =>
        {
            //if (IsBusy)
            //{
            //    return;
            //}

            //IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    ItemPic = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                //IsBusy = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I uploaded a [sample here](https://github.com/XfHua/select-photo-xamarin.forms) and you can check. Feel free to ask me any problem if you have.

Comment: i am already implementing it. it's in my base viewmodel wich it inherits from. Also all my other properties work just fine

Comment: yeah i just found out that i was not using my implementation of the propertychanged event. it's different then yours but still it's a good answer

Comment: yeah i just found out that i was not using my implementation of the propertychanged event. it's different then yours but still it's a good answer

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score -1):

You can use CrossMedia Plugin, example:

```
  await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
  var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

  var filestream = file.GetStream();
  byte[] buff = ConverteStreamToByteArray(filestream);

  image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(buff);
  filestream.Dispose();
```